# Class<T> Constructor, Trying to make T Nullable

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I have two class definition that are actually the same.
What i'm trying to do is make the T attribute Nullable

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public Boolean IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; } = default;
    public String Message { get; set; }
    public String Error { get; set; }

}
public class ApiResponse
{
    public Boolean IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
    public String Error { get; set; }
}
```

is there any way to simplify?
is for my job, I just came out of curiosity.

Comment: class ApiResponse<T> where T : class

Comment: What is your plan to merge the two classes, that is, what should happen to change `ApiResponse` to a `ApiResponse<T>` where this is no existing `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `T` to be `Nullable` implies that `T` must be a `struct`.  This means `ApiResponse<T>` must have the constraint that `T` is a `struct`.  You can also reduce code by inheriting from `ApiResponse`.

```
  public class ApiResponse<T> : ApiResponse  where T : struct
    {
        public Nullable<T> Data { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have two completely unrelated classes. Might be helpful if they had an inheritance relationship.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public Boolean IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
    public String Error { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponse<T> : ApiResponse
{
    public T Data { get; set; } = default;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what my answer, except I also constrain `T` to `struct`.